# How to prevent GitHub Actions from being run based on name of the branch merging into other branch

Tags: github-actions

I have the following workflow:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
```

I only want GitHub Actions to run when the branch I'm making the PR from does not start with "random/name*".

I found this in [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

```
on:
  pull_request:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches-ignore:    
      - 'mona/octocat'
      - 'releases/**-alpha'
```

but it only excludes it when making a PR to that branch, I want it to ignore branches I'm making the PR from. Is this possible?

Comment: You could check the PR `head_ref` at the job level ([you can see the PR event context payload here](https://gist.github.com/colbyfayock/1710edb9f47ceda0569844f791403e7e)). However, you can't check this at the workflow `on` trigger level. You will need an if expression in the `job` to run it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if: ${{ ! startsWith( github.head_ref, 'random/name') }}
steps:
```